# Punctuation and sentence structure

Tags: punctuation

> "I knew we were holed deep under the waterline, I could more or less
> feel it in my body, something vital torn out of the ship echoed in the
> pit of my stomach, some mischief done, deep, deep in some engine room
> or cargo hold."

It is posed the following question:

**How does the writer use language to describe the experience of being on board a ship struck by a torpedo?**

I have to analyse two answers given by student A and B. None of them highlighted the structure of this sentence. Indeed, the author uses commas rather than semicolons. Does it mean that it is a list of events?

What I would answer:

*The writer used a comma between "waterline" and "I" rather than a semicolon, then did the same between "my stomach" and "some mischief". Indeed, the writer listed events starting by the fact that he was aware about the extent of damage: "holed deep under the waterline". The second event, he wants to show how it was so serious confessing that he could feel it: "I could more or less feel it in my body"; a strange sensation which conveys his fear and adrenalin rush. Last, the narrator put the damage in the lower part of the boat.*

Am I correct?

Comment: The passage is not a list of events, but an analysis of the writer's feelings as he knows instinctively that the ship has been damaged.

Comment: Why didn't he use semicolons? And how to justify this punctuation?

Comment: Why do you think he _should_ have used semicolons? Use of punctuation is often a matter of stylistic choice. I would have started a new sentence after _waterline_, but this author chose not to.